# Makefile: Calling a recipe within another recipe will not run-dry it

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Let's say I have a Makefile looking like this

```
file1:
    $(MAKE) unittest
    @echo "Making test file"
    touch file1

unittest:
    @echo Running test. In reality recipe will include many lines

.PHONY: unittest
```

My goal is to have a recipe to only run unit tests, but I also want to run them before creating the file (file1) and I don't want to run them if file1 exists.

This works when I run make, but I notice when I try

> make file1 -n

file1 will be created and it is somehow due to having the make unittest call in the recipe.

Any clue about what is going on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `+$(MAKE) unittest`, I think.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That did not work unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either one of us is confused, or there's something about your makefile or environment you didn't share, or you have a buggy version of GNU make (what version do you have and what OS are you using?  The version of GNU make that ships with MacOS is known to be old and Apple has made changes to it that have added bugs).

Doesn't reproduce on my system:

```
$ cat Makefile
file1:
        $(MAKE) unittest
        @echo "Making test file"
        touch file1

unittest:
        @echo Running test. In reality recipe will include many lines

.PHONY: unittest

$ ls file1
ls: cannot access 'file1': No such file or directory

$ make -n
make unittest
echo Running test. In reality recipe will include many lines
echo "Making test file"
touch file1

$ ls file1
ls: cannot access 'file1': No such file or directory
```

**ETA**

It's clear you don't want the `file1` to be created if you run `make -n`.

But, your question didn't make clear whether you *want* the sub-make invocation of `unittest` to happen when you run `make -n`, or whether you *don't want* it to happen.

If you want `unittest` to be run but you don't want `file1` to exist, but you do want to use `.ONESHELL`, then you're out of luck.

If you don't want `unittest` to run *or* `file1` to exist when you run with `-n`, you can prevent it by fooling `make` into not noticing that the recipe is a recursive make invocation; all you have to do is not use the variable `MAKE` in the recipe.  However, note that this has other side-effects particularly if you use `-j` to enable parallel builds:

```
NR_MAKE = $(MAKE)

file1:
        $(NR_MAKE) unittest
        @echo "Making test file"
        touch file1
```

Comment: Corrrect. I had this extra option at the start that change the behaviour
.ONESHELL:

Comment: Well, that will definitely do it.  Make can only either run each line one command of the recipe at a time, in which case when you use `-n` it will not run "normal" commands but will run "recursive make commands", as in my example above.  Or, it can run the entire recipe in a single shell due to `.ONESHELL`, in which case when you use `-n` it will either run the entire recipe as a "recursive make command", or it won't run any of the recipe.  You can't have it both ways unfortunately.